# How to Delete Images from a folder in Public after update of the image in Laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel, image, slug

I tried to update a form including a file(image) and to have the old image deleted. The update works fine but the old image is unable to delete. I tried this code but the image is not deleted. Please, help me. Thanks in advance.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $slug   = SlugService::createSlug(Category::class, 'slug', $request->title);
    $request->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'category_image'=>'image'
    ]);
    if ($request->hasFile('category_image')) {
        $image          = $request->file('category_image');
        $newImageName   = uniqid().'-'.$request->title.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location       = public_path('/categoryImage');
        $OldImage       = public_path('categoryImage/'.$request->category_image);
        $image->move($location, $newImageName);
        Storage::delete($OldImage);
    }else {
        $newImageName   = $request->category_image;
    }
    Category::where('id', $id)->update([
       'slug'=>$slug,
       'title'=>$request->input('title'),
       'details'=>$request->input('details'),
       'category_image'=>$newImageName
    ]);
    return redirect('category')->with('success', 'Category Successfully Updated');
}
```

Comment: When I dd('$request->category_image') inside the if statement does not yield the image's name whereas the image name is displayed when used in the inside the else statement. I cannot not figure out what is it I am not getting right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    ...

    $category = Category::find($id); #new

    if ($request->hasFile('category_image')) {
        $image          = $request->file('category_image');
        $newImageName   = uniqid().'-'.$request->title.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location       = public_path('/categoryImage');
        $OldImage       = public_path('categoryImage/'.$category->category_image); #new
        $image->move($location, $newImageName);
        unlink($OldImage); #new
    }else {
        $newImageName   = $request->category_image;
    }

    #you can simplify this as
    $category->slug = $slug;
    $category->title = $request->title;
    $category->details = $request->details;
    $category->category_image = $newImageName;
    $category->save()
    
    return redirect('category')->with('success', 'Category Successfully Updated');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete old image like this , if image is not in root of your storage insert your file location inside storage before image name.

```
unlink(storage_path('/location_inside_storage/'.$OldImage));
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. When I dd('$request->category_image') inside the if statement does not yield the image's name whereas the image name is displayed when used in the inside the else statement. I cannot not figure out what is it I am not getting right.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'photo' => 'nullable|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,gif|max:10000',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->phone = $request->phone;
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        // Delete old photo from folder
        Storage::delete('images/' . $user->photo);

        $imageName = time() . '.' . $request->photo->extension();
        $request->photo->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
        $user->photo = $imageName;
    }
    $user->save();

    return redirect('/')->with('message', 'User updated successfully!');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).